# Facebook deferred deep link works when testing with App Ads Helper, but doesnt work with Real facebook ads

Tags: flutter, facebook, deep-linking

I'm using Flutter and have integrated Facebook SDK to receive Facebook Deferred deep link.

using below pluging for receiving app links

```
flutter_facebook_app_links: ^3.0.1+6
```

my deferred deep link

`app://value1_value2_...._valueN`

```
void initDeferredDeeplinks() async {
    String? deepLinkUrl;
    try {
      deepLinkUrl = await FlutterFacebookAppLinks.initFBLinks();
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        deepLinkUrl = await FlutterFacebookAppLinks.getDeepLink();
      }
      workWithLink(deepLinkUrl);

    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

The Deferred deeplink works when I send test deep link from [App Ads Helper tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper), but when I try on a real ad, it doesnt return the deferred deeplink.